# Creating and populating a new dictionary with entries from old

Tags: python, dictionary

```
def makeNewDictFromOld(oldDict):
    newDict = {}
    for key,value in oldDict.items():
        if value compared to something else is true:
            newDict[key].append(value)
    return newDict
```

If I do this I get an error saying `KeyError: last key of old dict`.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: There is no 'last' key in a dictionary. Dictionaries are unordered. You get the `KeyError` for the **first** key in the ['arbitrary' dictionary order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-python-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary).

Comment: It also isn't clear what you expect `newDict` to become, for a given `oldDict`. Do you expect the values to be lists? How are values collected per key? Why use lists in the first place when all `key`s are unique anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access a key that doesn't yet exist; your `newDict` is **empty**.

If you wanted to populate `newDict` with lists as the values, you need to first set the key to an empty list. Do so with [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
for key,value in oldDict.items():
    if value compared to something else is true:
        newDict.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
```

This sets `key` to `[]` *first*, unless the key is already present in the dictionary.

However, since all keys in the old dictionary are unique, you may as well just use:

```
for key,value in oldDict.items():
    if value compared to something else is true:
        newDict[key] = [value]
```

That is, unless you were entirely confused and just wanted to set the value directly, and not create lists:

```
for key,value in oldDict.items():
    if value compared to something else is true:
        newDict[key] = value
```

Last but not least, you could create the new dictionary entirely in a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
def makeNewDictFromOld(oldDict):
    return {key: value for key, value in oldDict.items()
            if value compared to something else is true}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean.

Both the key and the value are different for every "row" in the dictionary. It's a date as key with a corresponding value to that date.

Would I use the `newDict.setdefault(key, []).append(value)` in the for loop and it would populate the rest of the dictionary as well=

Comment: @Gurkmeja101: use it instead of the `newDict[key].append(value)` expression, so in the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the help. And I'm sorry that you had to guess as to what I needed help with. Made a mistake on how dictionaries work.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this instead of **append**

```
def makeNewDictFromOld(oldDict):
    newDict = {}
    for key,value in oldDict.items():
        if True:
            newDict[key] = value #assign directly instead of append
    return newDict

dict_ = {"name":"name1","age":35}
print makeNewDictFromOld(dict_)
```

Comment: @Gurkmeja101: so why were you using `.append()` in the first place? Did you get this confused with lists? It would have helped if you had given us an expected output, then it'd have been clearer from the start and we wouldn't have had to guess here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes I was entirely sure what to use. Haven't used dictionaries before so I'm sorry for the inconvenience. Appreciate all the help though!